# configure httpd.conf for PHP ( You don't have permission to access /php/php-cgi.exe/index.php on this server. )

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache successfully on WINDOWS and can open an HTML file with no issues. I also installed PHP on the server. I configured Apache and PHP as per the followng tutorials:
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-apache-on-windows/
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/

As mentioned apache allows me to open the html file in my website. when adding a php file I get error:
`You don't have permission to access /php/php-cgi.exe/index.php on this server.`

PHP is installed to c:\PHP and apached in c:\apache24

I have tried a few options to fix the https.conf file but without any success.

My config file snippet is below:

```
<Directory "c:/WebPages">
   #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    ##Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    ##AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    ##Require all granted

    #Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
Allow from all



</Directory>
```

This allows me to view the html file but not the php so am thinkign I need to allow permission to the c:\PHP folder but have no idea what?

any advice welcome. Thanks as always.

Comment: why install all that yourself, when you could just install a WAMP-type package and get it all done for you, INCLUDING having the appropriate fileysystem permissions set for you?

Comment: Hi Marc, is WAMP not for dev environments and not advised for production servers?

Comment: wamp is just prepackaged (W)indows version of (A)pache, (M)ysql, and (P)HP. they're about as production ready as any other self-installed copy of the same apps.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your CGI folder isn't at your PHP install folder. Try adding these lines of code to your httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "c:/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If you didn't install PHP at c:\php, change that to wherever you installed it. Remember, use forward slashes instead of back ones (I always get mixed up with that; to much Linuxing I guess).